# How to Remove repeated words in a string in php

Tags: php

I have a string that contains many words such as:

```
$str = "FileZilla Portable FileZilla 3.9
        FileZilla Portable Additional Versions
        7-Zip Portable 7-Zip Portable 4.42";
```

I want to delete all dupplicates and return each word only once:

```
$str = "FileZilla Portable 3.9
        FileZilla Portable Additional Versions
        7-Zip Portable 4.42";
```

How can I do it with php ?

Comment: you have your answer down check it and mark it as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
$str = "FileZilla Portable FileZilla 3.9
        FileZilla Portable Additional Versions
        7-Zip Portable 7-Zip Portable 4.42";

$arr = array_unique(explode("\n", $str));
$arrLength = count($arr);
for($i = 0; $i < $arrLength; ++$i){
    $arr[$i] = implode(" ", array_unique(explode(" ", $arr[$i])));
}
$str = implode("\n", $arr);

echo $str;
```

Here are the relevant references:

- [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)
- [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)
- [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: @Saty Oh, yes. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code.

```
$str = "FileZilla Portable FileZilla 3.9 FileZilla Portable Additional Versions 7Zip Portable 7Zip Portable 4.42";

$arr = explode("\n", $str);
foreach($arr as $st) {
   echo implode(" ", array_unique(explode(" ", $st)));
}
```

But numbers (7Zip) not removing...

Comment: This solution works fine, it's removing one `7Zip` from the third line.